# How to get cache name with a script

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, cache

I have a script that needs to get an object's cache name. Basically this:
[image: Cache name example]

I have tried with

```py
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].domain_settings.cache_directory
```

It works inside Blender's UI, even with the Python Console, but when executing the script it retrieves this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modifiers'
```

Does anyone know how to make the script actually get the correct object, so it is possible to access the fluid modifier's cache name?

Comment: The context is different when executing the script from when you are hovering the modifiers tab UI, so the *selected_object* lost its pointer to your object. You can store a reference to the object somewhere or access it with its name at any time, for example using `bpy.data.objects.get("my_name")` - note that this will throw an error if the object is not in the active scene or view layer or if you somehow changed the object's name :)

Comment: Thanks! That would work but I need to get the selected object name first. I'll work it out!